# Reverse an int array

Tags: java, arrays, function

I want to reverse an int array in java and this is the code but it throws an error `arrayOutOfBound` exception.

```
class reverse_number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar[]={1,3,4,2};
        int ar1[]=new int[4];

        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
            ar1[i++]=ar[ar.length-1];
        }

        for(int i=0;i<ar1.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(ar1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `ar1[i]=ar[ar.length-i-1]`

Comment: in addition to the error, the logic is flawed as well, since you assign the same item from `ar`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    int reveArr[] = new int[arr1.length];

    for(int i = 0 ; i <arr1.length;i++){
        reveArr[i] =arr1[arr1.length-i-1];
    }
    ...
}
```

You are incrementing `i` twice. When you try to access the array using index beyond its capacity (when `i` is on the last iteration, and you access `arr1[i++]`, the index you are accessing exceeds the length of `arr1`), it is bound to give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
```

then in this loop you are increment `i` again

```
ar1[i++]
```

This is not necessary, just use `i`

Comment: you might as well suggest fix for assignment from `ar`

Comment: meh, got to leave something for the OP to study

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .

```
class reverse_number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar[] = { 1, 3, 4, 2 };
        int ar1[] = new int[4];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ar1[count++] = ar[i];

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ar1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```